# How to make custom $form_fields textbox 100% width in Edit Media wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to make custom $form_fields textbox in Edit Media width 100%. This is what I currently have, however the text field is very small. I did notice that other fields on the media page like "Alternative Text" are on a separate line all together, how can I achieve similar?

```
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", "add_image_source_url", 10, 2);
function add_image_source_url($form_fields, $post) {
$form_fields["media_credit"] = array(
"label" => __("Media Credit"),
"input" => "text",
"value" => get_post_meta($post->ID, "media_credit", true),
);
return $form_fields;
}
```

any help would be much appreciated :)
Thanks,

Comment: Just used your code in my dev install. The field looks like this - http://imgur.com/inT3rZD So what's the problem?

Comment: hmm, here is what mine looks like: http://imgur.com/qL3E0nk

Comment: You customized lots of things there, didn't you. Well, fire up Chrome Dev Tools or whatever and inspect that element. Maybe you need an extra line or two in the stylesheet in your specific case.

Comment: I've done no customization in Edit Media other than this, I updated to wp 4.5 using Dazzling bootstrap theme

Comment: Which theme is that? This one? https://wordpress.org/themes/dazzling/

Comment: yes, thats the one

Comment: It's weird because I just tried it on my install  and it didn't change anything on edit media page. I guess, you have some plugins hooking into that page.